# How can I monitor command usage on a system, possibly outputting p8s metrics?

Tags: iptables, monitoring

I'm trying to debug some usage of the `iptables` command.  The idea is that I have a number of things changing and calling `iptables`, with parameters, and at different times that it's hard to get some reasoning on the matter without more information.  So, I'd like to record usage and calls to tools that update iptable rules, which would include the `iptables` command.  Is there something that does this?  My initial idea would be to shadow the iptables command on the system and record the calls from the wrap/proxy command.

Are there ways to monitor a command and it's usage, and possibly output some metrics to Prometheus?  The last part about p8s metrics would be a nice to have, but the translation from some other system of record to p8s would likely be easy to implement.

Comment: If you have rules that trigger rule changes. Then this is self modifying code. Stop it. There madness lies.

Comment: I'm trying to identify all the madness with this and with luck stop the crazy.  But first there's too much noise and nothing appears as an obvious culprit.

Comment: Maybe `auditd` will satisfy your requirements?